Who can see my internet traffic
I can see this question has been asked before but just wanted a bit more clarity specific to my setup. So I wfh using a corporate vpn to access the company's erp system ( sap). I dont need the vpn to access the web on my work laptop. Next to my work laptop I have my own personal laptop setup for personal use. Both share the same Internet connection .
So my question is can my work it dept see all traffic generated from both laptops or just my work laptop. Bear in mind I don't log into any services on my work laptop such as Hotmail and Gmail. I have done so in the past but  stopped and changed my pw.
If they can see traffic from both how can I get round this ? Can I use a vpn on personal laptop to encrypt the traffic so they can't see it ?
Thanks

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Depends on how your VPN is setup. If its a piece of software on your work laptop that isnt installed on your private laptop, then your employer cant see any of your personal traffic. If you connect through a hardware based solution and also use your private laptop to connect through that, your emplyer can intercept your private traffic. Mind you, logging into services like Hotmail or Gmail would not expose any of your login information. Even if your employer intercepts it, it would still be encrypted between you and that service.

Just your work laptop, but what they can see can vary a lot.
Aside from the data flowing through the VPN - which they have full visiblity over, many work systems have security and integrity tools, which to various extents can monitor your usage of that pc. Stuff like data loss prevention tools, or security tools.
On a well set up network (its 2024, no one uses hubs), no client should see traffic meant for another client. Its either only sent to the client that is the destination (with wired ethernet and switches) or encrypted when it goes through the air.
While you should not be using your work system for personal use - no system in your network should be getting traffic meant for another system unless your network is set up to do so.
Most modern internet services also tend to be encrypted end to end. Unless there's some kind of MITM proxy (some work place networks may do this), no one can read the traffic between your system and the destination.
Practically the answer's no, work can't snoop on your personal laptop. Keeping work and personal system's a good idea but there's no need to airgap your own stuff from work.

Thanks the corporate vpn I use is it just to it capture my keystrokes on the erp system or does it also re route my general Internet traffic through it as well ? Or does that go through my isp.

Depends on how its set up, but VPNs are set up to keep people out, not spy on people.

I will ask the question to the it depth and my isp tomorrow. General  surfing on company resources is a cost in terms of bandwidth and network management is that correct ?
